# How does one call a person who is next in line within a business process?

Tags: grammar, terminology, business-language

A business process consists of several consecutive steps, such that if a process flows from one step to another then the pair of steps is considered single-way connected. How does one call a person or a team which is fed with results from previous step to begin their work?

For example, on a car production pipeline, painting only starts when each detail is ready to: cut, pressed, and welded. So, painting stage "consumes" prepared components.

What is a proper name, in general, for a person or team in such a relationship?

I have several alternatives, and all of them seems unsuitable for me:

- consumer — one is called a consumer when she actually gets a complete result, not intermediate one;
- customer — same;
- next-in-line — too general, too impersonated;
- stakeholder — too general.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but, in car manufacturing, the painting is one of the first processes to take place, usually immediately after press and welding. :)

Comment: I haven't really dig any information about it so I just dumped here the first example I imagined in my head. But after you noticed that, I found that, speaking about automotive, process is really far from what I've thought of it before. :) Thank you for your remark!

Comment: I work for Nissan so I know a thing or two about the automotive process.  :)  We produce two completed cars every 57 seconds!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downstream (deliverables) is the popular term in the software industry. Similarly, upstream is also used to denote the predecessor step.

Comment: Supply chain model is what I'm actually talking about. But I only found a supplier-customer pair terminology. The latter, to not be confused with end customer, should be replaced by another word. Anyway, it seems very close to the solution.

Comment: Producer-consumer is also a pairing popular among software developers. Not sure if it is used in the SCM space.

Answer (score 1):

A *dependent* step is one that relies on a previous step to occur. It doesn't necessarily mean next-in-line exclusively, but certainly it can be used with appropriate verbiage (upon what does it depend?).

Usage example:

> Packaging is *dependent* upon the completion of QA.

Edit:
Another option is *subsequent*. (or simply *next step*)

> The *subsequent* process after QA is Packaging.
>
> The *next step* after QA is Packaging.

Answer (score 0):

**[Conduit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conduit)** might remotely fit your the next in line assumption.

> A means by which something is transmitted: *an arms dealer who served
>   as a conduit for intelligence data.*

<sup>Source: The Free Dictionary</sup>

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think it doesn't actually fit because conduit stands much more for the transport than for an object being transported or a next node in line which is being transported to.

Answer (score 0):

An associate could be a more basic part of a business process than a senior associate.

Answer (score 0):

In my business, we occasionally refer to ***internal customers*** who will receive and make use of (possibly develop/transform) the product of one team before that product (or whatever they make from it) goes to another team and/or, ultimately, to an *end-user*.